# Change Activity when connected to server (TCP)

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin, android-activity

After I check if inputs are correct, I bind the activity to service to send it ip, port... and start a new activity. But I want to start the activity only after app successfully connected to the server or else don't.

First activity

```
btnConnect.setOnClickListener {
    //some checks
    //if checks pass

    //bind to service
    Intent(this, MyService::class.java).also { intent ->
            intent.putExtra("ip1", ip1)
            intent.putExtra("port1", port1)
            bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        }

    //++should wait here until connected++

    //open new activity
    val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Connection in service

```
fun startConnection(ip: String, port: Int) {
    try {
        socket = Socket(ip, port)
        //if successful continue below
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: I want to start new activity when I successfully connect to server, not immediately like now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about passing a callback to the `startConnection` method? It'd look something like this

```kotlin
btnConnect.setOnClickListener {

    Intent(this, MyService::class.java).also { intent ->
            intent.putExtra("ip1", ip1)
            intent.putExtra("port1", port1)
            bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        }


    startConnection("localhost", 8080, onConnectionEstablished = {
        val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    })
}


fun startConnection(ip: String, port: Int, onConnectionEstablished: () -> Unit) {
    try {
        socket = Socket(ip, port)
        onConnectionEstablished()
        //stuff
```